# codeIgniter form_error() not display error when validation fails

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

codeIgniter validation error not displaying errors when validation fails, i have tried var_dumping the validation_errors() and form_error() function. This is annoying because i have used form_validation in 6 CI projects.

```js
public function create(){ 
    $error = '';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwordConfirm','Confirm Password','trim|matches[password]');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone','Phone','trim|required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('bank_name','Bank name','trim|required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('bank_acc_name','Account name','trim|required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('bank_acc_no','Account no','trim|required');
  
  if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE){
   
   $response = $this->user_model->create_user();
  }
  
  if(count($this->form_validation->error_array()) > 0){
   $error = 'Check input provided';
   var_dump(validation_errors()); die();
  }
  
  $data = [
   'error'=>$error,
   'form'=>[
    'username'=>[
     'value'=>  set_value('username'),
     'error'=>  form_error('username')
    ],
    'email'=>[
     'error'=>  form_error('email'),
     'value'=>  set_value('email')
    ],
    'password'=>[
     'error'=>  form_error('password'),
     'value'=>  set_value('password')
    ],
    'passwordConfirm'=>[
     'error'=>  form_error('passwordConfirm'),
     'value'=>  set_value('passwordConfirm')
    ],
    'phone'=>[
     'error'=>  form_error('phone'),
     'value'=>  set_value('phone')
    ],
    'bank_name'=>[
     'error'=>  form_error('bank_name'),
     'value'=>  set_value('bank_name')
    ],
    'bank_acc_name'=>[
     'error'=>  form_error('bank_acc_name'),
     'value'=>  set_value('bank_acc_name')
    ],
    'bank_acc_no'=>[
     'error'=>  form_error('bank_acc_no'),
     'value'=>  set_value('bank_acc_no')
    ]
    
   ]
  ];
  //var_dump($data); die();
  $this->load->view('header');
  $this->load->view('register',['data'=> json_decode(json_encode($data),FALSE)]);
  $this->load->view('footer');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my bug, in my config file, i autoloaded form_Validation instead of "form_validation" with a small later v. Banging my head against the wall

Comment: Dont sweat it. I once worked on a problem for 3 days before I realized I was using $ajax instead of $.ajax